# how to diagonalize this symbolic matrix?

Tags: matrix

```
m = {{0, 0, w}, {0, t, -w}, {w, -w, r}}
```

use equation `P^(−1)A P`, how to obtain P with Mathematica?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the suggested approach?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{vals, vects} =  Eigensystem[m = {{0, 0, w}, {0, t, -w}, {w, -w, r}}, Cubics -> True];
```

and then your `P` is:

```
P = Transpose@vects;
```

too long to post here.

Edit:

You can easily verify that the resulting matrix is diagonal. Like this:

```
dd = Inverse@Transpose@vects.m.Transpose@vects;
Diagonal[dd, #] & /@ {-2, -1, 1, 2} // Simplify
(*
  {{0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0}}
*)
```

Comment: Many Thanks first! I've tried your method, my new question is after use P1 = Inverse[P], now I have P^1, however I didn't see a diagonal matrix after P1.m.P. Could you help me with this? Thanks again!

Comment: @erik see edit,please

Comment: **1.** You don't have to do inverse as vects is orthogonal matrix thus Inverse[vects]=Transpose[vects].

**2.** Symbolic eigenvalues and eigenvectors for matrices larger that 2 x 2 are basically useless even though identity (as shown above) could, probably, be verified up to 4 x 4 but most likely not beyond that.

**3.** If you seed the random values for w, r, t, then you can verify the identities in no time!

Comment: Dear @KonstantinKonstantinov: instead of posting a patronizing comment you could have asked why I did **1.**,  why I don't think **2.** is true and why I think you're wrong in **3.**. Now you've lost the opportunity. Have a nice day.

Comment: Sorry @belisarius, I am not following you, especially on your **#3**. So, if you could elaborate that would be great. If you are referring to my numbering then **1** is an identity, for example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov, I believe the issue is that not all matrices are real, in which case P is unitary and not orthogonal.

Comment: @evanb, yes, you are right. Then we need to use ConjugateTranspose instead of Transpose and that will probably kill Mathematica symbolic evaluation.

Comment: Why no up-votes for this answer? Some things just pass by unnoticed I guess...